# Pointers and References as member variables of const objects

Tags: c++, constants

The following code compiles fine. However I wonder if it is legal C++. So more specific, if I have a const object, am I allowed to modify variables through pointers/references of that object?

```
class Foo {
public:
    int* a;
    int& b;
    Foo(int* _a, int& _b) : a(_a), b(_b) {}
};

int main ( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    int x = 7;
    const Foo bar(&x, x);

    *bar.a = 3; //Leagal?
    bar.b = 7; //Legal?
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's legal, as const-ness of the class means that the class member is constant. `a` is a pointer, so the address the pointer points to is constant, but the value stored at that address need not be.

Hence `bar.a` is effectively an `int * const`, not an `int const *`.

As, after initialization, a reference cannot be made to refer to another entity anyway, it does not matter for `bar.b` whether `bar` is declared `const` or not.

The constant variant of a pointer is a constant pointer, not a pointer to a constant. The constant variant of a reference is a reference, not a reference to a constant.

Small digression: You should be careful with references as members anyway in connection with const-ness, as the following will probably compile

```
struct Y { int m_a; };
struct X {
   const Y & m_y;
   X (const Y & y) : m_y (y) { }
};

Y y;
y.m_a = 1;
X x (y); // or const X x (y) -- does not matter
// X.m_y.m_a == 1

y.m_a = 2;
// now X.m_y.m_a == 2, although X.m_y is supposed to be const
```

As it is possible to assign a pointer to non-const to a pointer to const, you can build an analogous example with pointers. Remember that `const` does only guarantee that YOU will not modify a variable via this very variable, it cannot guarantee that the contents of the variable are not modified at all.

Answer (score 3):

I find the best way to think about `const` in C++ is that it protects the physical bits of the object.  It has no real protection for objects that it refers to.  You can control the object definition with `const` methods to provide deeper protection of values but by default C++ really only protects the physical object itself

One of the reasons why C++ allows you to modify the contents of a pointer through a `const` value is that it really can't stop you.  Imagine for a second that C++ disallowed that particular construct.  You could trivially violate it by doing the following

```
size_t t1 = (size_t)bar.a; // legal 
int* t2 = (int*)t1;        // legal 
*t2 = 3;                   // exactly the same as *bar.a = 3
```

Comment: ...until you make it mean what you need it to mean using overloads.

Comment: @aschepler correct, you can use tricks to give deeper const semantics but by default it is really only protecting the physical bits

Comment: I get errors on the first two lines of your snippet.  I get an invalid conversion from `int*` to `size_t`, and then an invalid conversion from `size_t` to `int*`.  To make it work, you'd have to add casts, and of course, there are all sorts of things you can bend/break with casts.

Comment: With a c-style cast, there's no reason to go through a `size_t` intermediary.  You can simply say `int *t = (int *)bar.a;`, which would perform a `const_cast` (assuming `bar.a` was a pointer-to-const originally, of course, which is the hypothetical).  The ability to cast away constness isn't really a good rationale for it not to be present in the first place.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson i think it represents an interesting view point on it though. Pointers are really just numbers and C/C++ allows the easy translation between pointers and numbers (in many respects because C allowed it).  Given the easy transition between the two formats protecting pointers by const seems a little absurd since it's so easy to violate.

Comment: @JaredPar, by that logic, `const` decorators on pointers and even `const` itself is absurd, since you can always cast it away, and you can obtain a pointer to (almost) any object and then cast away the const.  I think a better rationale for the constness rules we have WRT pointers is the idea that pointing to an object is an association and not implicitly ownership, and therefore should not be deep.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson i agree that the logic applies itself to raw pointers as well. I understand this isn't the intent of the language.  I'm more trying to give the OP an example of how fragile `const` on pointer takes can be given the semantics inheritted from C